# Show ready-made plots with different style

Tags: plotting

I have several existing plots and I want to put them together with distinguishing style. However I don't want to evaluate them again since each takes a very long time. So I write the following but it doesn't work, what is the correct syntax?

```
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding a `PlotStyle` to each plot and being patient

```
Show[MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, ColorData[97, First@#2], Line[b]}} &, {plot1, plot2, plot3}]]
```

but here is a way to do it in `Show[]`

---

[image]